# I'm looking for file in my template project that i can put option

Tags: android

I'm looking for file in my project that i can put two option

I'm trying to use
`this.mobileAccessibility.setTextZoom(100);` or
`webView.getSettings().setTextZoom(1000);` to prevent devices to change the original
web site font size in my web view app ( I'm using template )

and looking for code to can zoom in / out in my app

and i don't know where to put codes :(

[image]